# Oracle JRE 7 and 8 both will not install on previously Javaless win7

Tags: windows-7, installation, java, eclipse, jre

Simple question I thought I'd never have to ask, since I've done it hundreds of times before: How can I install JRE?

I have a Win7 x64 Pro box with no Java environment, running as an admin user.  I'm trying to install [JRE8u45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), but every time I try, the installer progresses a while and then ends with error 1603 with no additional detail.

The events in the Event Viewer for go like this:

> Product: Java 8 Update 45 (64-bit) -- Error 1722. There is a problem
>   with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the
>   setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or
>   package vendor. Action installexe, location: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\installer.exe, command: /s
>   INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\" REPAIRMODE=0

That was an "error," and the next two are "information":

> Product: Java 8 Update 45 (64-bit) -- Installation failed.

...and:

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Java 8 Update
>   45 (64-bit). Product Version: 8.0.450. Product Language: 1033.
>   Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Installation success or error
>   status: 1603.

### Things I've tried

1. [This article](http://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml) linked to [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000988).  I installed it and tried again, but got the same error trying to install JRE.
2. I tried right-clicking the installer `jre-8u45-windows-x64.exe` and choosing "Run as administrator".  Same result.
3. I tried Java 7 u79, and it also did not complete, and didn't even give an error code.  Interestingly, it seems to have finished (in that Java-related items are now on the Start Menu), even though it said that something (didn't say what) interrupted it, and Event Viewer shows this:

> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Java 7 Update
>   79 (64-bit). Product Version: 7.0.790. Product Language: 1033.
>   Manufacturer: Oracle. Installation success or error status: 1603.

Um...OK.  Another entry at the exact same time says:

> Product: Java 7 Update 79 (64-bit) -- Installation operation failed.

At this point, the configuration applet works, but, my end goal was actually running Eclipse (for non-Java development, hence getting the JRE instead of the JDK), which now does not complain that there's no JRE, and instead complains:

```
---------------------------
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
---------------------------
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

So I guess it...half-installed.  When I OK that dialog, it then says:

```
---------------------------
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
---------------------------
Error: could not find java.dll
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And another OK gets me:

```
---------------------------
Java Virtual Machine Launcher
---------------------------
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

After that, a popunder I didn't discover until later:

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=2
C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700\splash.bmp
-launcher H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll
-startup H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata fa8_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar H:\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Rant: Really, on a fairly pristine--I'm just installing my development tools these last few days--fully patched, theoretically supported version of Windows, there's no way to install either the latest JRE, or the latest of the previous major version?

Comment: @Ramhound that's odd because my domain account is listed as being of the Administrators group in the user manager.  Is that not normally sufficient?  I've installed all the other software I need just fine, and I would guess programs like Firefox, Apache OpenOffice.org, Thunderbird, pgAdmin, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, etc. write to the registry during their installation processes.

Comment: Also what to make of http://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml saying it's a known issue that's under investigation... so, I just can't install Java on this computer?  Super.

Comment: @Ramhound, in my first update I mention that I installed that hotfix and tried again, with no difference in results.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry it wasn't even the first update, it was the initial paragraph.  Feel free to suggest an alternate organization.

Comment: @Ramhound or maybe now it's better.  But if one missed it in the first paragraph I'm not sure one will find it in the middle either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May 12 2015's new Windows Updates ran, then after a restart, I was able to install JRE 8 u45.  Not sure which exact update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution worked for me.

Go to the installation folder and run the javacpl.exe click the Security Tab, untick "Enable Java content in the browser" Click Apply. 
Then put the tick back in the box, Apply, OK and Open your browser, go to http://www.java.com click "Do I have Java?" and click on the Verify Java version button.

This sounds stupid, but it worked for me after 3 hours of messing about with installers, the registry, user accounts etcetera...